# Force binding to occur after apply ControlTemplate?

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, custom-controls, controltemplate

Hey, I am building a CustomControl that has a bunch of dependency properties and a few visual parts like, for example, a Canvas, a TextBox, etc.
Problem is, upon assigning a value to the dependency properties, I need to perform certain actions on the visual elements, namely I need to add the new dependency property's value to the Canvas, but when the binding kicks in and the value is assigned, the ControlTemplate has not yet been applied and so it crashes.

What is a good way to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution is to do a null check in the dependency property handler to prevent crash, and also override the relevant method in which you know that the visual tree is constructed (OnApplyTemplate most likely) and do the same thing there to initialise your visuals.

Comment: Duh, it was so simple, my problem is that I'm still not sure how the life cycle is for a WPF control. Enabling a breakpoint on the Changed eventhandler of a Dependency Property I could see that it was being set multiple times, some null values and finally the value set from my binding. I thought that if I did a null check there, I'd miss the binding value. Anyhow, thanks.

Comment: Well, the component life cycle is not exact science, there are tons of factors in place. Like how deeply nested your control is and what kind of parents does it have (ListBox for example has its own life compared to simple Grid, etc), what kind of framework you use, how do you initialise you ViewModel, etc etc.